# How to remove right side text from google bar chart?

Tags: javascript, graph, google-visualization

I am using [google bar chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/). I want to remove right side text with blue mini rectangle which i mark by red circle. Please see image below:-

[image]

Here is my code:-

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Household Income');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Holder');
      data.addRows([
        ['Under 20K', resdata[0].un20],
        ['20 to 50K', resdata[0].fr20to50],
        ['50 to 75K', resdata[0].fr50to75],
        ['75 to 100K', resdata[0].fr75to100],
        ['100 to 150K', resdata[0].fr100to150],
        ['150 to 250K', resdata[0].fr150to250],
        ['250K and up', resdata[0].up250]
      ]);
      var options = {};
      // Instantiate and draw the chart.
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('myBarChart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `legend.position = "none"` in the initial configuration object. See the API docs (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#configuration-options) for further explanations to the configuration options.

Comment: yes, it's work `var options = { legend: { position: "none" } };`

Comment: appreciate the comment with example code - +1